# Убрать фокус в поле ввода начального адреса в routePanelControl при использовании нескольких карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста как решить проблему.
На странице используется несколько карт, в каждую из которых добавляется routePanelControl, задается конечная точка маршрута, начальная - пуста. При использовании нескольких карт на странице фокус передается в поле ввода начального адреса маршрута последней routePanelControl , таким образом страница скроллится вниз. Подскажите, как можно этого избежать?

```html
// массив объектов idMaps хранит ID карты и конечный адрес маршрута
for(var k = 0; k < idMaps.length ; k++){
    // Создаем карту с добавленной на нее кнопкой.
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('y-map-' + idMaps[k].ID, {
            center: idMaps[k].COORDS,
            zoom: 12,
            controls: ['routePanelControl']
        }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });
                
    routePanelControl = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');
                
    // Зададим опции панели для построения маршрутов.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
        allowSwitch: false,
        collapseOnBlur : true,
        // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
        reverseGeocoding: true,
        // Зададим виды маршрутизации, которые будут доступны пользователям для выбора.
        types: { auto: true, pedestrian: true }
    });
                
    // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        // Тип маршрутизации.
        type: 'masstransit',
        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
        fromEnabled: true,
        // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
        toEnabled: false,
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
        to: idMaps[k].ADDRESS
    });
 
}
```

Если использовать обратный порядок заполнения карт (с конца)
for(var k = idMaps.length-1; k >== 0 ; k--) ...
, то фокус появляется соответственно в первой сверху карте, однако некоторый скролл вниз все же происходит.

Comment: Пока нет опции, чтобы запретить автофокус в инпуте панели маршрутов. Постараемся добавить её в будущем. Спасибо за сообщение!

Answer (score 3):

Отключить автоматическую фокусировку на панели можно через опцию autofocus:

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: ['routePanelControl']
});

var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

control.options.set({
    autofocus: false
});
```

Comment: @Reni Посмотрите пожалуйста ответ. Будущее уже настало?

Comment: @0xdb , да, оно прекрасно